# Selecting one repeated multiindex in a dataframe on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
major minor col
0     0     5
      1     6
      2     4
0     0     8
      1     5
      2     6
1     0     3
      1     6
      2     9
1     0     5
      1     1
      2     7
```

First I'd like to get

```
major minor col
0     0     5
      1     6
      2     4
0     0     8
      1     5
      2     6
```

and then select over both major '0's, that is, choose the first major 0 or the second:

```
major minor col
0     0     5
      1     6
      2     4
```

or

```
major minor col
0     0     8
      1     5
      2     6
```

Unfortunately `df.xs(0,level=0,drop_level=False)` doesn't exactly fit the job, since it maintains major '1's in the index, although empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand your data structure. I'm right now working with

```
                 val
major minor col     
0     0     5      1
      1     6      1
      2     4      1
      0     8      1
      1     5      1
      2     6      1
```

I still don't understand how in your case you have *two* major zeros, since I get only one with the same structure. Therefore, I can't tell you exactly how you could pick any of the *major*s.

Using traditional slicing, you can get where `df.major == 0` using

```
df[df.major == 0]
```

In order to select any single of the subgroups now, it depends on how they're different. Do they have another unique feature? Then you could do

```
df[(df.major == 0) && (df.someColumn == someValue)]
```

(notice the brackets). Otherwise, if you know there are `3` rows per group, `df[df.major == 0].iloc[:3]` (or `3:`) will give you the records.

Also, have a look at the (currently experimental)`df.query()` ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax)).

Generally, you can do stuff such as

`df[df.major == 0]` to get all the values where the major is zero. If it's a (labeled) index or a normal column does not matter. You can also stack these to do

`df[(df.major == 0)

I start with

```
In[264]: df
Out[262]: 
                 val
major minor col     
0     0     5      1
      1     6      1
      2     4      1
      0     8      1
      1     5      1
      2     6      1
1     1     3      1
            6      1
      2     9      1
      1     5      1
            1      1
      2     7      1
```

and then I do

```
In[263]: df.query('major == 0')
Out[261]: 
                 val
major minor col     
0     0     5      1
      1     6      1
      2     4      1
      0     8      1
      1     5      1
      2     6      1
```

Comment: Yes it works... But isn't there a way to do it with slices? How do I now select one of the two 0's in the edited example?

Comment: The way to get two major zeros is by concatenating two dataframes with a major zero in each. There is not a `.major` attribute in a dataframe. You need to access each index level by `df.index.get_level_values('major')`, for instance.

Comment: I think it'd be much easier if you'd just provide short code to reproduce your dataframe ... if the question is still open.